# Difference between [ ] and ( ) to create new Scala objects

Tags: scala

Just looking at Scala Akka and wondering what is the difference between the following object initialisation methods.

```
system.actorOf(Props[HelloActor], name = "helloactor")
```

and

```
system.actorOf(Props(new HelloActor("Fred")), name = "helloactor")
```

I can understand the second one, `Props(new HelloActor())`, but what is the first one, `Props[HelloActor]`? I don't know its name so can't google for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props is a case class with a companion object. In Scala code you will see two major ways people will construct objects. One is with a constructor on a class. Another major way is by calling an `apply()` method on a companion object.

If you look at the source code of `akka.actor.Props` you will notice that the companion object has four `apply()` methods, two of which you are referencing in your code above. At time of writing their signatures are:

`def apply[T <: Actor: ClassTag](): Props`

`def apply[T <: Actor: ClassTag](creator: ⇒ T): Props`

As helpful sugar Scala allows you to call an apply method without stating the apply method so in your first example you can rewrite that as `Props[HelloActor]()` and the compiler inserts the `apply()` method for you. Next, if a method has no arguments you may omit the parenthesis. So the call becomes `Props[HelloActor]` as you have pointed out above.

Your second example calls the second `apply()` method.

As to your question about how does the real HelloActor class get instantiated that is a little more complicated. All of the explicitly defined `apply()` methods eventually call a special `apply()` method that is generated by the nature of Props being a case class. This apply calls the constructor on Props which creates an akka.actor.IndirectActorProducer. This class holds many strategies that can be used to instantiate the actor. In your simple case it eventually uses reflection to construct your actor.

Comment: can I know more about the special apply method which is eventually called by the other apply methods. Is it something specific to akka? or is it a nature of scala?

Comment: The special apply() method is part of Scala and is created when you add the case keyword to your class. So any case class you create will have an implicit apply() method created that has all of the same parameters as your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets `[]` in Scala denote the use of a [generic class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/generic-classes.html.html).  Generic classes are classes which take a type as a parameter.  The class name between the brackets in the instantiation of a generic class is the argument for that type parameter.

So in your case, the `Props` class has 1 generic parameter, and the line `Props[HelloActor]` is providing the type `HelloActor` as the argument for that generic parameter.

Comment: so is **Props[HelloActor]** an object? if yes, how can **system.actorOf()** use that object to initialise another real HelloActor object?